# Cannot run JSON_VALUE in SQLite database (.db file) in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: database, sqlite, ssms, sql-server-2016

I want to update some JSON data in SQLite database (.db file) and I met a problem.

I work in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio where I added SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox through Visual Studio Extensions. I'm succesfully able to connect to this file and I'm also able to run a query on this database (create table, insert data etc.). The only problem is that a table I want to update has a JSON column and I need to use the JSON_VALUE function to get some data from that column. And when I run  `SELECT JSON_VALUE([data]) FROM myTable`, I get an error message:

```
ErrorCode : 1
Message   : SQL logic error
no such function: json_value
Result    : Error
```

for a query `SELECT sqlite_version` I got a result `3.24.0`.

What am I doing wrong? What should I add to system to make this thing working? In standard SQL everything is working fine. SSMS is version 14.0.
I also tried programs "DB Browser for SQLite" and "SQLiteStudio" and also did the same example in Visual Studio and got exactly the same error.
Any hints (please step by step, I'm totally new to SQLite) would be appreciated.

Comment: You will need to [compile and install](https://sqlite.org/loadext.html) the [JSON extension](https://sqlite.org/json1.html) to get proper JSON support in SQLite

Comment: I didn't write 'step by step' for no reason. I really don't know how to achieve this stuff. Thanks in advance.